# Cannot display jpeg images

Tags: php, image, xampp, jpeg

I am writing some web pages using XAMPP, but cannot display jpeg images. Maybe I have to change some configuration files,could someone show me how to fix this.

Comment: show us the code, also tag PHP,XAMP?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Add/Delete Powers</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="superhero.jpeg" width="100" height="100" align="left" hspace="10">
<h1>Comic Book<br>Appreciation</h1><br>
<h3>Editing Character Powers</h3>

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you GD support is enabled or disabled..For that Goto : localhost/ and then click on phpinfo() tab ..then search for 'GD' ...In that if GD support is enabled or disabled..if disabled you need to change it to enabled to work with images..hope it'll be helpful for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of the files embedded in your web page may be they are not linking to their respective objects...

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for finding the path of the files whether they are wrong or right...

Comment: I don't think that's the reason cause I replaced the jpeg image by a png one and it works just fine.

Comment: From the above code you have given, i think **superhero.jpeg** should be written as **superhero.jpg** , try this.....

Comment: oh my god,this fix the problem!!The image was a jpeg one but changing to .jpq in the code actually works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the image is getting loaded properly:
Check this example:

```
<?php
$the_path_to_image = '/path/to/image';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($the_path_to_image);
```

Comment: what example??I don't see anything